# Fan Beam reconstruction artifacts in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a set of pictures on which I need to perform Fan Beam projection and reconstruction by MATLAB. But for these pictures I've got weird artifacts.

Following the documentation on `ifanbeam()` function, I've written the following code:

```
ph = phantom(100);
d = 100;
fan_proj = fanbeam(ph,d);
fan_reproj = ifanbeam(fan_proj,d);
imshow(fan_reproj)
```

And it worked well:

[image]

But then i tried to explicitly save the phantom image on the drive (instead of loading it from MATLAB itself), load it from the drive, and perform the same operation.

```
ph = phantom(100);
imwrite(ph, 'phantom.png');
clear;

ph = imread('phantom.png');
d = 100;
fan_proj = fanbeam(ph,d);
fan_reproj = ifanbeam(fan_proj,d);
imshow(fan_reproj)
```

And the result was suffering from weird artifacts:

[image]

Why does this happen? What exactly changes in the image so the result of this function also changes so dramatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `imshow` (by default) expects the input data to have values between 0 and 1. This is true when you first construct the phantom.

```
ph = phantom(100);
min(ph)

    0

max(ph)

    1
```

But when you load it back from the file it will have values between 0 and 255. This is because it was saved and loaded back in as an unsigned 8-bit integer:

```
ph = imread('phtnom.png');

class(ph)

    uint8

min(ph)

    0

max(ph)

    255
```

And when you use `imshow` with the default color scaling it will *still* be [0,1] causing the extreme contrast that you are seeing.

You can use `[]` as the [second input to `imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_lowhigh) to ensure that the full dynamic range of the image is displayed.

```
imshow(fan_reproj, [])
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't expect the issue to come from this side. Thank you very much for the help.